# Bind web applications to different addresses in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

Webapp named **BOB** must be reachable only through `192.168.3.56:8080`

Tomcat is listening on two IP addresses on the same socket:

```
<Connector port="8080" 
 protocol="HTTP/1.1"
 address="192.168.3.56"/>

<Connector port="8080" 
 protocol="HTTP/1.1"
 address="192.168.3.57"/>
```

Despite the fact that I can't find any suitable parameter in the [Apache Tomcat 7 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html), can **BOB** be bindable to a specific `<Connector>`?

Answer (score 1):

I've made an unexpected pretty solution searching deeply far and wide in Apache documentation.

Having two working connectors (ad I did), a way to bind a single webapp to one of them is to create a new `Host` in `server.xml`, as in my case:

```
<Host name="my.dns.app1.name"  appBase="webapp1-name" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
                directory="logs" 
                prefix="my_log_file." 
                suffix=".txt" 
                pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

and then asking to our IT managers to register one new records on our DNS (or even in your file hosts on your OS)

```
192.168.3.56 -> my.dns.app1.name
```

Why using DNS? Because attribute `name`, as written in virtualhost on Apache documentation, expects a FQDN or something to resolve... maybe...

Now, every time the `my.dns.app1.name:8080\BOB` is invoked, BOB will answer!

PN: `appBase="webapp1-name"` must be created at the same level of the default `webapp` folder first and it will contain BOB as a normal web application. Every time `my.dns.app1.name:8080\BOB` is called, Tomcat will look inside the `webapp1-name` folder looking for BOB.